# How to prevent food colouring changing the taste of food?

Tags: baking, flavor, coloring, decorating

I am a keen baker with a big sweet tooth. I often use coloured icing and sponge when I bake, but often the colouring I use changes the taste of the icing/sponge.

Does anyone know how to prevent the food colouring changing the taste of food or how I can minimise it?

The food colouring I use is: Dr Oetker

Comment: How much food coloring are you using? Do you know the ingredients of the food coloring? I'm thinking if you're using a natural food coloring (and I think Dr Oetker doesn't use artificial coloring), for example beet juice, you could be getting a bit of that flavor but it's hard to say without knowing the ingredients and how much you're using.

Comment: Is the colour changing the _actual_ taste, or merely the _perceived_ taste? They say, “The first bite is with the eye”, and it's known that colouring does affect our perceptions. (Of course, a way to tell would be to try both coloured and uncoloured pieces with your eyes closed, mixed up, and see if you can distinguish them by taste alone.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you use the same Dr. Oetker colouring that I have used in the past, which is advertised as a 'gel' colouring, then you have to use a *lot* to get a good intense colour.

You may have better results (colour and taste-wise) getting proper concentrated gel food colourings, like those made by [Wilton](http://www.wilton.com/store/site/product.cfm?id=3e30b2d9-475a-bac0-5d5c3db846dfd354). You need to use much less than cheaper brands so you don't run the risk of flavouring the food, and you can even use them in meringues without ruining the structure.